# How to install ImageMagick on 10.6 (Snow Leopard) using a precompiled binary (without a package manager)?

Tags: snow-leopard, command-line, image-editing, package-management

The wish is to manipulate images from the command line using the ImageMagick tools.

No package manager because:

1. The MacPorts `port` and Homebrew `brew` package managers have Xcode dependencies.
2. Xcode is a 4.1GB download for version 3.2.6 and I am not willing to wait for that.
3. Loads of dependencies exists in the packages themselves.
4. For example ImageMagick using homebrew depends on `pkg-config`, which fails to download: `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`.

The ImageMagick.org supplied precompiled binary release is also no option as that [ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0.tar.gz](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0.tar.gz) binary is compiled for Darwin version 12 (Mountain Lion) which results in "segmentation faults" when being run on Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

How to install ImageMagick on 10.6 (Snow Leopard) using a precompiled binary (without a package manager)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Search for an old version of the binary ImageMagick release named "ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin10" that runs on 10.6.8, for example:

   - http://tools.robodoc.net/tools/imagemagick/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0.tar.gz
2. Download and extract the files.
3. Move the ImageMagick-6.6.7 folder to your home folder.
4. Start terminal and execute this command: `$ export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/ImageMagick-6.6.7";export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH";export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"`
5. Ready

Comment: Thanks for that link to the old version of ImageMagick! These should be available from ImageMagick themselves...

Comment: This answer works fine for 10.6